# Creating a heatmap overlay in uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to create a heatmap overlay ontop of a geographic map of an area using MapControl in a UWP app.

It should be able to take a list of latitude and longitude coordinates to create an image that I can use as a tile source.

I've had a look at a few articles namely Gheat.net and creating heatmaps with Dylan Vester but they all use System.Drawing to create their heatmap images which is not supported in UWP.

How would I go about generating the Heatmap image?

Comment: Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/overlay-tiled-images) to make custom tile overlay for bing map

Comment: Thanks but its the heatmap image to act as the tilesource that I'm struggling with as I don't know of any tools I can use in UWP to draw the heatmap image.